can all my dimension tables hav the same primary key?
I have the below tables:
info: (symbol/ country/ city/ address/ market/ industry...)
balance sheet: (symbol/date/ total debt/ total assets...)
income statement: (symbol/date/ net income...)
statistics:(symbol/ enterprise value/ market cap...)

used technologies; postgresql/talend/power bi
needed: I need to do the database model conception , create a datase(which I did on postgresql and talend) then I need to connect it to power bi and create a dashboard with filters(date/market/industry/symbol)
my questions:
1st scenario: I added IDs to each table on Talend and created a fact table that contains all the other tables' IDs, but that does not work on power bi when it comes to the filters since they do not impact all the tables even when the relationship is active and goes both ways.
2nd scenario: I used the info table as my fact table (without the created tables IDs on talend) and connected all the tables using "symbol", that way all the filters are interacting with all the tables
HOWEVER my issue is I think the second scenario is not correct when it comes to the model conception.
can I keep the 1st scenario and keep the created fact table and add to it the values that I'm goanna need for the filters? will that be correct from a model conception perspective?
or should I only use the symbol to connect everything?
Any other suggestions or examples or resources I can read?
Thank you!
